# Is there a way to change URL by htaccess ? ex:

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is there a way to change URL by htaccess ? 
ex: current url is www.abc.com/about want change to www/abc.com/test/about
It's not only "about" link but also all links want to add "/test/" before the link

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to achieve that effect using Apache URL Rewriting. Just make the following changes to your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^test/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)$ /$1 [NC]
```

Explanation

The first line of code does as it says, it turns Apache’s Rewrite Engine on. The following 3 lines checks if the requested URL is already a valid file, it only redirects if it isn’t. Meaning , if your website already contains a directory like /test/mydir, then the redirection will not occur. The final line rewrites the URL giving us the desired output.

Comment: Thank you Bishal Sapkota, but it's not work on my site. "/test/" is virtual directory (not exist on server).

Comment: The answer should work except for the leading "/" of the RewriteRule target - it should write "RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ $1 [NC]".  In terms of ease and covering all cases, I replaced the regex [all letters and numbers] by the more general (.*) one.  The browser URL would always accept "...somesite.com/test/..." and the server will provide the corresponding "...somesite.com/..." content.